# Iframe to Parent Communication using PostMessage, get the Iframe that sent the message

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain, postmessage

So the scenario is that I send some data using `postMessage()` from an iframe that is not going to have an `id` attribute associated to it, and there will be more than one iframes on the page. The `src` URL of the iframe is a site that is hosted on another domain, thus I can't access parent and set widths and heights due to cross-domain policy.

On the host window, besides receiving the data from the iframe, I want to resize that iframe to 10x10. So my question is, what property from the received message event refers to the actual iframe, and how can I set the width and height?

**The content of the iframe:**

```
<html>
...
<body>

<script>
   parent.postMessage(dataToSend,'*'); 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**The content of the Host:**

```
<html>
...
<body>
...
<script>

// The listener that retrieves the data from the iframe
function iFrameListener(event){
...
}
addEventListener(window,'message',iFrameListener);
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: you can set a name attrib on the iframe, and it will appear as `window.name` to the iframe JS. you can use `event.target` from `top`'s message event to get the window that sent the message.

Comment: I wouldn't have access to the iframe that is being generated..setting the name is not possible

Comment: well then you're going to have a hard time identifying the right iframe tag. you can try matching the frame's `location.href` to the `iframe.src`, but that can be less-than-perfect in the case of redirects or url formatting (local vs abs). maybe you can use JS to set a name attrib on the iframe, and maybe that will be available to the iframe context as `window.name`, but i think that might have to be set before the page loads; worth a shot.